# How can I open a Kendo Window in a view from an ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I need to check for existing entities when users add from a kendo grid. This works fine.
What I am stuck at is showing a Kendo window on top of the grid if a possible duplicate is about to be added, with options for merging, adding anyway or cancelling.

I've got a DivotAdminController and it's View. I've added a partialView with that same name as the DivotCreate Action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Divots_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Divot divot)
{
    using (var context = new DataContext())//Check for Barcode match and ask user what to do if found
    {
        var existingDivotId = context.Divot
            .Include("CategoryLevel1")              
            .Join(context.Containers, ast => ast.ContainerId, cts => cts.Id, (ast, cts) => new { Divot = ast, Container = cts })            
            .Where(a => a.Divot.Barcode == divot.Barcode)
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.Divot.CaptureDate)
            .First().Divot.Id;

        var existingDivot = context.Divot.Where(a => a.Id == existingDivotId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (existingDivot != null)
        {
            return PartialView("Divots_Create", existingDivot);
        }
    }

    if (divot != null) //if not a match save the new entry.
    {
        var containerid = (guid)tempdata["selectcontainerid"];
        divot.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        divot.CaptureDate = DateTime.Now;
        divot.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        divot.Username = User.Identity.Name;

        _repository.AddDivot(divot);
    }

    return Json(new[] { divot }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

When a match is found, the `return PartialView("Divots_Create", existingDivot);` line executes, but nothing happens client-side.
I want to know if there is a way to have the partial view show as modal, or kendo window show as modal if a duplicate is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action add a model error :

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "User name already exists");
```

Assign an event handler for the grid on error :

```
.Events(events => events.Error("handleError"))
```

Handle errors on client side via javascript function ( show window or something else)

```
    handleError = function (args) {
        if (args.errors) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.each(args.errors, function (propertyName) {
                   var error = this.errors[0];
                });
            });
        }
    };
```

See this [Blog post](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/13-08-29/handling-server-side-validation-errors-in-your-kendo-ui-grid) for more details